# C# static method question

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

I do not understand what exactly happen behind the scenes when using static class with static members in multithread environment.
I have a server application where clients very often read-write to SQL db. For that, I have created static class with static members SQLConnection,SLQDataReader etc. But as I understood, static class is just one, shared between threads, so how it deals with multiple requests at the same time? Would not be better just have non static class used for that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine as long as you're only using static methods and no static fields. Once you decide to use your first static field, you'll have to worry about thread safety.

Comment: Thanks. Could you describe me please how it works in my current solution? I do not understand how it handles more requests if there is only 1 instance

Comment: There are many ways for a static method to create thread-safety or other concurrency problems.  What about `Application.DoEvents`?  This answer isn't true irrespective of context - it depends entirely what is in those methods.

Comment: Those methods are for reading and writing into DB, all of them take a string as parameter and employ SQLCommand.

Comment: Static SqlConnection is a horrible idea, like Aaron describes in his anwser. I do agree that methods are OK, and fields require special attention. This means that as long as the static methods don't use some kind of shared state, you're safe

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to diverge from the other answers and say that it is a very bad idea to have a `SqlConnection` and especially `SqlDataReader` as global state.  It is a huge, huge design smell.  A few questions to consider:

- Will the connection always remain open?  If so - are you aware that this wastes resources on the database server, and may even cause you to exceed the number of licensed connections?
- If the connection will not remain open - what steps will you be taking to prevent the scenario where one thread closes the connection while another is using?  In fact your code does not necessarily even need to be multi-threaded for this to happen; in order to prevent it, every database operation must first save the original connection state, open the connection if closed, then restore the original state after finishing.
- Are you serializing access to the `SqlConnection`?  If so, will you lock it for the entire duration of a database operation, which would severely impact overall app performance by causing a lot of unnecessary wait times?
- If you are not serializing access, what happens when one operation tries to execute some unrelated operation while another is in the middle of an important transaction?
- If making a "global" `SqlDataReader`, can you be absolutely sure that only one thread at a time will ever use it, and that thread will never need to execute another query before it is finished with the first result set?  Even if `SqlDataReader` were thread-safe (it isn't), thread-safety rules are out the window if you actually destroy the object in question and replace it with a new one.

A `SqlConnection` should really be treated as a unit of work - you create it when needed, and dispose of it when finished.  A `SqlDataReader` is not even a unit of work - it is a throwaway object for which there is absolutely no reason to keep at a global level.  Even if you implement a singleton as others have apparently suggested, you are setting yourself up for a huge amount of trouble later.

**Update:** If these "members" are actually factory methods then that is different.  The way the question was worded implied that a single connection was actually being shared.  If you are simply providing static methods to *create* connections/queries then you can disregard this.

Comment: I do share one connection, what would be better way with the same speed? Opening the connection makes a little lag (100ms and above). The server communicates with DB at least a few times per second.

Comment: The only safe way to share a `SqlConnection` in a multi-threaded environment is to ensure that only one thread is using it at a time, which kind of defeats the purpose of multi-threading.  You really don't need to share a single `SqlConnection` object in order to share a physical connection, though; ADO.NET takes care of that for you behind the scenes with connection pooling, as long as you don't disable it.

Comment: Oh, I am now quite desperate. I just need to let all clients to work with DB at the same time, so how to do it properly with the advantage of multithreading?

Comment: Just create `SqlConnection` instances as needed, connection pooling will minimize the actual number of connections and open/closes.  The hard work has already been done for you, you just have to use it.

Comment: Also you mean each client should have its own SQlConnection instance? And also sqlreader etc.?

Comment: No, each **unit of work** should use its own `SqlConnection`.  And `SqlReader` has trivial overhead - you should use a new `SqlReader` for **every query** (and dispose it properly when done).

Comment: Unit of work? On my server, each client has its own Client class assigned once connected, so I though I will just add it there.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET or other web application?  Or RPC/remoting?  Because if it's ASP.NET, the "Client" would be in the session state, and storing a `SqlConnection` there is a **very** bad idea.  In a server application, you need to be creating `SqlConnection` instances *when they are needed*, not leaving them hanging around just in case you need them later.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. It is WInForm server app. So I hope there wont be the unpleasant connection lag - when I call Open it lasts sometimes 300ms, sometimes 50..

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there's no such thing as a "WinForm server app."  Does this software really run on a server or does it just connect to one?  It changes the question significantly if it's the latter...

Comment: Well, it is server (tcplistener) app written in C# with WinForms GUI :)

Comment: Oh... a bit unusual but I understand.  ADO.NET's connection pooling should handle most scenarios then - it may seem laggy testing with just 1 client, but when you have 100 clients there will almost always be an already-open connection.  And, O/T, but if you're getting a 300 ms delay on just opening the connection then the lag is probably going to be even worse on queries - if the database is on a remote VPN or something then you're liable to run into scale problems later.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: +1 Using multiple connections will be *faster* in the end, because you can have simultaneous writes to the database, instead of having a number of threads wait for a lock to the connection. This defeats the purpose of multithreading, because most threads will be waiting for the lock most of the time

Comment: Agreed & voted up.  I can't think of any valid reason to have a static SqlConnection.